# How can I send automated emails from bluehost?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, email, newsletter

I want to send newsletters and event information to my customers. Sending manual emails will take time. So, I was thinking of sending automated emails.

I just want to upload all my contact details to MySQL database in Bluehost where my website is placed and send automated emails. But, I don't know how to do it. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Use Mailchimp.com instead (or another alternative such as Sendgrid, Sendinblue, Sendpulse etc..). 
They all have automatization and integration tools you need.

Sending bulk emails via hosting is not good idea.

1. Most of them would go to spam boxes. (becuase you don't have reliable mail server in your shared hosting website)
2. You can easily be blocked by the Hosting Provider because of rulebreak.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this with posts, there are plugins that would do this fairly well. Just search for "posts to newsletters" or "posts to emails" in wp add plugs. If you're looking to do something more unique, you could use php mail() in a file to loop through contact emails, then call the file regularly with a remote cron job (as I believe you can't set up a cron job on the server) site like cron-job.org.

See:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php
https://cron-job.org